# Laravel Model Events - perform actions on specific column update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

as we all know Laravel has model events which are fired on certain instances, and we can perform actions on them, like created, creating, saved, saving, etc. What I want to know is that how can we know which column was updated on lets say 'saved' event like a user was updated and of course saving and saved events were fired, inside these events can one know which column was updated and perform actions accordingly ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can hook into the `saving()` method and check through the `getDirty()` method.

Comment: If you are using `timestamp`. then when ever you inserted or updated record, it will mention the date and time. you will get more information regarding at there [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent]

Answer (score 4):

As @Joel Hinz said you can use [`getDirty()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) method.

> getDirty() - get the attributes that have been changed since last sync

This method will return an array with names of changed columns:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::saving(function ($user) {
        $columns = $user->getDirty();

        foreach ($columns as $column => $newValue) {
            echo $column; // One of the changed columns.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but i found it and I've a better solution.

Use `$model->wasChanged('FIELD_NAME')`

This will return true/false if fields was changed on last save.

If you combine this with boot method:

```
public static function boot()
    {
        /*
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            Log::emergency('creating');
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
            Log::emergency('updating');
        });

        static::deleting(function ($model) {
            Log::emergency('deleting');
        });
        */
        static::updated(static function ($model) {
            if ($model->wasChanged('FIELD_NAME')) {
              // YOUR CODE
            }
        });
        parent::boot();
    }
```